# Why does SKPaymentTransactionObserver when added to paymentQueue trigger the delegate function paymentQueue?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am using the StoreKit framework to implement auto-renewable subscriptions.  My implementation works but I have an issue with the paymentQueue.  When I add the SKPaymentTransactionObserver to this queue, it triggers the same delegate function as when I add an SKPayment.  Is this avoidable?

The paymentQueue delegate method that gets triggered when either one of the following is executed:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(SKPaymentTransactionObserver)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(SKPayment)
```

DELEGATE METHOD

```
// Observe transaction updates.
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    for transaction in transactions{
        //print("rawValue: \(transaction.transactionState.rawValue)")

        switch transaction.transactionState.rawValue{
        case 0:
            // DO NOT 'finishTransaction'
            return print("paymentQueue.purchasing")
        case 1:

            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            self.registerPurchaseSuccess()
            return print("paymentQueue.PURCHASE SUCCESS")

        case 2:

            if let error = transaction.error{
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                return print("paymentQueue.FAIL.error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            }else{

                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                return print("paymentQueue.fail. no errors")
            }


        case 3:
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            return print("paymentQueue.pending.restored purchases")
        case 4:
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            return print("paymentQueue.pending")


        default:
            return print("paymentQueue.unresolved issue ...")
        }

    }
}
```

Upon successfully adding my SKPaymentTransactionObserver to the SKPaymentQueue, i end up triggering 'self.registerPurchaseSuccess()' - which is pointless, as I have not made any payment transactions - just added an observer to the SKPaymentQueue

Comment: You are probably seeing a renewal event for a previous purchase. One of the first things your app should do when it starts is register the payment queue observer and process any pending transactions. It is incorrect to only register the observer immediately prior to the purchase. Also, why are you switching on the `rawValue` instead of the enumeration cases?  Using the case names would make your code easier to read.

Comment: @Paulw11 I add the observer in the appDelegate, immediately as the app starts like you mentioned.

Comment: Ok. So then you are probably seeing a renewal purchase. You can examine the transaction details and the receipt t determine this. Auto renewing subscriptions renew at an accelerated rate when using the sandbox.

Comment: @Paulw11 so you're saying that adding the observer should not trigger the delegate method, unless it was updating a previously unfinished SKPayment transaction?

Comment: Yes, or a transaction that fired while the app wasn't running.